# Oracle find if a value in one table exists more than once in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables - `tblrespondent` and `respondent_person_id`.  Both of these tables have a column called `full_name`.  `tblrespondent` has duplicates in `full_name` and `respondent_person_id` does not.  Some values are in both tables and I would like to know which values in `respondent_person_id` appear more than once in `tblrespondent`.

This is what I've tried.

```
SELECT * FROM RESPONDENT_PERSON_ID 
WHERE full_name IN 
    (SELECT full_name, count (*)
    FROM TBLRESPONDENT 
    GROUP BY FULL_NAME 
    HAVING count (*) > 1)
```

tblrespondent

```
full_name
---------
JohnDoe
JaneDoe
BruceWayne
JohnDoe
TonyStark
BruceBanner
TonyStark
```

respondent_person_id

```
full_name
---------
JohnDoe
JaneDoe
BruceWayne
TonyStark
```

### Desired Result

```
JohnDoe
TonyStark
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are on the right track.  The only issue is that the subquery returns more than one column.  So try this:

```
SELECT rpi.*
FROM RESPONDENT_PERSON_ID rpi
WHERE rpi.full_name IN (SELECT r.full_name
                        FROM TBLRESPONDENT r
                        GROUP BY r.FULL_NAME 
                        HAVING count(*) > 1
                       );
```

In many databases (with the right indexes), a correlated subquery might be faster:

```
SELECT rpi.*
FROM RESPONDENT_PERSON_ID rpi
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM TBLRESPONDENT r
       WHERE r.FULL_NAME  = rpi.full_name
      ) > 1;
```